# Create a user prompt that does not write to stdout

Tags: bash, go

In bash, there is a builtin called `read` which has the -p switch. For example:

```
read -p "Please enter a value: " value
echo "${value}"
```

If this file is then executed like `$ ./bashfile > result.txt`

You will end up with a file containing `$value\n`, but NOT `Please enter a value: $value\n`

In go, you can do something similar. Here's a section of code:

```
fmt.Print("Please enter a value: ")
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
value, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println(value)
```

If you were to run that with `$ ./goexecutable > result.txt`

The content of result.txt will look like `Please enter a value: value\n`

Is there an equivalent in go to the bash `<PROMPT>` string from read -p which prints to the command line, but not to stdout?

Comment: so you want something in `bash` that will write prompt and value to the file?

Comment: @ritesht93, OP wants something in Go with the bash behavior. Read the last line carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash's `read -p` just prints the prompt to `stderr`. You can tell by redirecting the stderr of your script to `/dev/null` and noticing that no prompt prints.

```
 ./bashfile > result.txt 2> /dev/null
```

You can do the same in Go using `fmt.Fprintf`.

```
fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Please enter a value: ")
```

Comment: Huh. Sure enough, you're right. I never would have figured that out on my own, thank you!